# Usage of 'not different'

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, negation

Take a look at this sentence.

> Many  apps are not good. Even some of Apple's 
>   own apps are not different.

I intend to mean some of Apple's own apps are not good. Is this correct?

Comment: It would likely not be interpreted to mean what you intend.  Try: *Many apps are not very good.  Even some of Apple's own apps are pretty bad.*

Comment: 1. Avoid using the first *not* in a case like this. "Many apps are poorly made (or whatever, but say it directly, rather than by using the opposite and then modifying with *not*) 2. It seems *no different* sounds better than *not different.*

Comment: Qs of this nature (composition, proof-reading etc.) are better asked on writersSE -- they could be considered off-topic here.

Comment: I would think you are looking for the idiom [no different](http://www.idiomsandexpressions.com/category/keywords/no-different)

Comment: "Even some of Apple's own apps aren't." Easy as pie. And "own apps" can go as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for "Many apps are not good. Even some of Apple's own apps are no different."

As an aside, hope you're writing something very smart to back up this sort of broadly scathing claim. Does "many" refer to thousands of apps you've checked? Which "some" of Apple's own apps? etc. Are you sure this is not just a biased opinion of your own? Because your audience will probably not tolerate highly personal opinions to which they cannot relate.

Comment: The OP asked a formal grammatical question by giving an example. Ths semantic content is irrelevant and there is no reason to believe the OP endorses it: he may be quoting a sentence he read and which annoyed him.

Comment: Thanks; 'no different' it is. As Georges said, it's just an example :)

Comment: Using more complex negatives than necessary is usually inadvisable (whoops, almost put 'not good'!) - and by this, I mean the structures rather than the individual words chosen. 'Many apps are poor. And this even includes some of Apple's.' The exception is when an odd example of litotes is used for reasons of style (perhaps to convey a hint of concession or humour, or to hedge a put-down). As mplungjan says, 'no different' is idiomatic and thus more acceptable.

Comment: @G: The OP says: "**I intend to mean** some of Apple's own apps are not good." The OP is asking a formal **semantic question**. The answer & relevant comments are based on semantics, not grammar. Either your definitions of _grammar_ & _semantics_ are in _not different_ cognitive boxes, or your reading comprehension skills are somewhere in that recent Colorado blizzard & being _not good_.